# Адаптивный шрифт css

Tags: css, css3, scss

Нашел интересную статью
https://habr.com/ru/post/501392/

Никогда не сталкивался с scss и не понимаю как им пользоваться
Необходимо создать файл style.scss и подключить его как обычные стили?

К примеру, прописываю в scss

```
$maxWidth: 1280;
@mixin adaptiv-font($pcSize, $mobSize) {
    $addSize: $pcSize - $mobSize;
    $maxWidth: $maxWidth - 320;
    font-size: calc(#{$mobSize + px} + #{$addSize} * ((100vw - 320px) / #{$maxWidth}));
}
```

Как я могу обратиться к ней из css файла и в целом, если такое отличие. Что лучше css или scss?

Возможно я ошибаюсь, что не так это мое предположение, все время работал с css...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `scss` - это надстройка над `css`, позволяющая в какой-то степени программировать стиля, а не просто задавать их. Использовать переменные, оптимизировать синтаксис, и все такое.
- подключать .scss файл напрямую как стиля нельзя. `scss` с помощью программы-препроцессора компилируется в `css` - либо локально на компьютере, либо "на лету" на сервере. но и в том и в этом случаях браузер получает скомпилированный `css`.
- скомпилированный `css` не обязательно будет оптимальнее самописного. к тому же добавляется трудность при отладке - порой непросто бывает понять, в каком месте `scss` нужно править, глядя на css-свойство в веб-инспекторе.
- грубо говоря, `scss` - это исходник для `css`.
- а есть и другие препроцессоры, например, `less`...

и вообще, все давно отвечено https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass/51423768#51423768 =)

Comment: `порой непросто бывает понять, в каком месте scss нужно править, глядя на css-свойство в веб-инспекторе.`, а как же настройка, которая позволяет создать `.map` файл? Тогда в инспекторе будет ссылка на `scss` с нужной строкой.